# I can't get parent page query in wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have tried this code but always return an empty query, and i don't know why.

`parent = MangaPage.objects.filter(title=Page.get_parent)`

Answer (score 3):

`get_parent` is a method on a specific instance of the `Page` class, it's not a property. You should not call it from the `Page` class directly, but rather from a specific page.

It should look something like this:

`parent = MangaPage.objects.get(title='Some Title').specific().get_parent()`

Essentially what you are doing in your code example is searching for a `MangaPage` that has a title equal to the *method* `Page.get_parent`, which of course there are none. You need to get the parent of a specific page instance.

Comment: What i want, i will use word series , in case of you don't know what is manga. I have a series that have story and genre, i need to make all eposde have same information, without write it again, so i give the parent the information like genre and need to respawn it to childern

Comment: I don't understand how I can help you much further. Sorry. It sounds like you just need to read the documentation.